# The annotation in property does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using Symfony 2.7 - When I want to generate getters and setters they tell me that:

```
The annotation "@doctrine\ORM\mapping" in property MostVenteBundle\Entity\commande::$lignes_cmd does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded
```

```php
<?php

namespace Most\VenteBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * commande
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class commande
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_cmd", type="date")
     */
    private $dateCmd;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="adresse_liv", type="string", length=33)
     */
    private $adresseLiv;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Client", inversedBy="commandes")
     * @ORM\joinColumn(name="id_client", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $client;


    /**    
     * @ORM/OneToMany(targetEntity="ligne_cmd", mappedBy="commande")     
     */
    private $lignes_cmd;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->lignes_cmd = new \Doctrine\Common\Collection\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set dateCmd
     *
     * @param \DateTime $dateCmd
     * @return commande
     */
    public function setDateCmd($dateCmd)
    {
        $this->dateCmd = $dateCmd;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get dateCmd
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getDateCmd()
    {
        return $this->dateCmd;
    }

    /**
     * Set adresseLiv
     *
     * @param string $adresseLiv
     * @return commande
     */
    public function setAdresseLiv($adresseLiv)
    {
        $this->adresseLiv = $adresseLiv;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get adresseLiv
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getAdresseLiv()
    {
        return $this->adresseLiv;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check the casing of the namespace, it has different casing in your error message than in your code, which sounds unlikely, so please confirm what's in your actual code. You also appear to be using a slash instead of a backslash in the annotation of the beforementioned property.

Comment: Also, classnames should be written in [CamelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) so that they can be autoloaded properly.

Comment: Using `@ORM/OneToMany` Instead of `@ORM\OneToMany` seems to be the issue.

Comment: @Yonel Quoting is meant for quotes, not for pre-formatted (error) text. Use code samples (indent 4 spaces) for pre-formatted text. You can even [hint the syntax highlighting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/254800) with `<!-- language: lang-none -->` for text only samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/**    
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ligne_cmd", mappedBy="commande")     
 */
private $lignes_cmd;
```

you wrote @ORM/OneToMany instead of @ORM\OneToMany